# angular button disable when form control empty

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to disable search button, when text-box empty. I tried to add disable attribute to search button. but its not working.

This is my html code:

```
<div class="col-md-5 pl-0">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Enter MTCN Number"
      maxlength="16"
      class="form-control mtcn-textbox"
      [formControl]="mtcn"
      required
      type="text"
      aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
    />
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button
        class="btn btn-primary"
        type="button"
        (click)="retrieveData()"
        [disabled]="mtcn"
      >
        Search
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me to achieve this?

Comment: it should be something like [disabled]="!mtcn.value"

Answer (score 0):

You can disable your button just using `[disabled]="!mtcn.value"`.
Or you can disable button if your form is not valid: `[disabled]="!myForm.valid"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [disabled]="!mtcn.value" or put your code into Form tag and giv it an id and use "form.valid"

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `mtcn` is a FormControl, which is always truthy. You want to check the value of the FormControl.

You have 2 possibilities.

**1. disabled attribute**

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter MTCN Number" maxlength="16" class="form-control mtcn-textbox" [formControl]="mtcn" required type="text" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="retrieveData()" [disabled]="!mtcn.value">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2. disabled class (since it seems you are using bootstrap)**

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter MTCN Number" maxlength="16" class="form-control mtcn-textbox" [formControl]="mtcn" required type="text" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="retrieveData()" [ngClass]="{ disabled: !mtcn.value }">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[disabled]="!mtcn.value"` would work, but I'd like to strongly advise against it. Assume you want to add some other validation rules (length, pattern, whatever) - you'd need to repeat the same thing twice, in the form control itself and in the button. In the long run, it'll get tedious to maintain and invite bugs.

Just go

```
<button [disabled]="mtcn.invalid">
```

Edit: Oh, and if you're using `[formControl]`, put the validation rules in the `mtcn` definition in the TypeScript, not in the template, right now you're mixing model driven and template driven forms.